# What trainer level do you have to be to max "power up" a pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

[image]
There's just an itty bitty amount left to power it up before it maxes out.

Comment: Seeing how every Pokemon's max CP goes up with each of your trainer's level up then I'm guessing it's the max level is for trainers which I believe is 50.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you level up the maximum CP for every pokemon also goes up. However every pokemon has a different maximum CP but the same pokemon will always have the same maximum CP for every trainer level. Therefor every time you level up as a trainer you will be able to increase the CP for all of your pokemon you will also see higher CP wild pokemon.